# How to handle multiple main villains in your campaign

Tags: gm-techniques, campaign-development, villain

I was hoping to pick your collective brains in preparation for my new 5e Eberron campaign starting in a few months.

Most of the blogs/books etc I've looked through look at campaign design with one central villain or antagonist as the focus. The circumstance I'm looking at is involving multiple villain groups including the PC's after the same Mcguffin but for differing agendas/goals with some crossover.

Any suggestions on how to use multiple groups in an effective way?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is way to broad. Do you have any actual *problems* running with multiple villains? *Those* might make good questions.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. The Stack Exchange is a Q&A site that works best for solving specific problems; traditional forums are better for open-ended brainstorming sessions.

Comment: This is a very good topic though. If you can split it into more precise questions about specific issues with multiple antagonists, I'll be glad to share my thoughts.

Comment: Thank you all apologies for such a broad topic I think I'm still in the brainstorming phase. Once I've crystallized what exactly it is I'm struggling with I'll update and hopefully you will be able to enlighten me.